# Different classes with same classname imported seperately in different components, overrides one another - React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

Suppose I have a component `ABC.tsx` in which I have imported CSS file `ABC.css`.

```
ABC.css

.header{
width:10%;
}
```

Again, I have another component `XYZ.tsx` in which I have imported CSS file `XYZ.css`.

```
XYZ.css

.header{
width:100%;
}
```

These classes are used in their respective component.

However, when I run my app, I notice that class from XYZ is being applied to ABC or vice-versa. Shouldn't classes be applied locally only from those CSS files to the component in which they were imported?

Does react process all CSS and put them before all HTML tags and they are applied according to the order in which they were processed? I am saying this because I can see in in the inspect's element tag there are 2  tag before the HTML begins, both containing the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually **styles in nested JS application will be applied to the header of your index** file so it will affect any part of your code. If you are using [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) *(If you not you may require `react-scripts@2.0.0` or higher)* one of the easiest ways **to make this work is to use `.module` extension for your CSS files**, to let the bundle creator make each class a unique one for you.

So let's say we got `ABC.css` we should add `.module` into it like this `ABC.module.css` and then import it like this:

```js
import class from "ABC.module.css" // route to ABC.module.css
// rest of your file
return <div className={class.header}></div>
```

*Besides the `.module` approach we can use many other great tools for scoping our CSS that available to React application like [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/), [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction), and many others.*

**NOTE:** Thanks to @hotpink, it is worth to mention, CSS styles on the same property will override each other based on their writing order or [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), so this behavior that we saw here will not be limited to nested applications (e.g React) and it may happen everywhere in our frontend applications.

Comment: Just to add to your correct answer, it's worth pointing out that this is not React-specific behavior. CSS has a global scope be default. "Two CSS properties walk into a bar. A barstool in a completely different bar falls over."